# Shell Scripting - Testing if a directory exists either in the current directory or in a parent / ancestor directory

Tags: bash, shell, mercurial, zsh

I am using the following code to detect if the folder `.hg` exists in the current directory. If it doesn't, then the function returns:

```
if [ ! -d ".hg" ]; then
  return
fi
```

How can I modify this to check if `.hg` exists either in the current directory *or* in a parent / ancestor directory? I'd imagine if it isn't an option such as `-d` then the solution is going to be recursive.

Comment: Are you only interested in direct ancestors?

Comment: Assuming a directory structure like `/foo/bar/foo2/bar2/foobar` if I am in `foobar` I want to know if `.hg` exists either in `foobar`, `bar2`, `foo2`, `bar`, or `foo`.

Comment: @KPthunder: You wouldn't want to know if it exists in `/`?

Comment: @SvenMarnach That's a derp on my part. Yes, `/` would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just cheat on this one:

```
if ! hg status > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    return
fi
```

`hg status` should be successful as long as you are somewhere inside a mercurial tree.

Comment: Awesome, this works. I'll accept the answer as soon as enough time as passed. Let me know if my understanding is correct: we are redirecting the output of `hg status` to `/dev/null` so nothing is printed and checking for failure in `hg status`. What does `2>&1` mean though?

Comment: @KPthunder: This redirects stderr (file descriptor 2) to stdout (file descriptor 1), effectively also sending stderr to the electronic Orcus.  This is necessary since `hg status` will print an error message to stderr if you are not inside a mercurial tree, and we want to hide this error message as well.

Answer (score 2):

This searches the preceding directories for the directory specified by d

```
    d=.hg
     r=1
        for i in $(seq 0 $(pwd|tr -cd '/'|wc -c)); do
            if [ -d "$d" ]; then
                r=0
            fi
            d=../$d
        done
        if [ r==1 ]; then
           return
```

Comment: I used `hg status > /dev/null 2>&1` in the past, but firing up the python interpreter took too long. This script made my mercurial prompt much faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to wrap the test in a while loop that continues until the current working directory is /, and to cd .. after checking for the presence of the .hg directory.